# How display Java Object by ajax calls

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have Spring 4 MVC web app, I would like to do a GET call with Ajax that returns a list of simple object. Suppose that the object is something like this:

```
class Categories {
   String name;
}
```

and calls is like this:

```
function getCategories() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "categoryFilter.html",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Than I would like to display this object inside a Spring form like this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="searchShop.html" modelAttribute="Categories">
    <c:forEach var="cat" items="${result}">
        <span><form:input path="nome" value="${cat.name}" /></span>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

I googling around and I see that I can append the result into a div or something similar but I can do something like that?

---

Thanks for your reply. My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/categoryFilter")
public Response showCategory() {

    List<Categoria> categoryList = categoryService.getAllCategories();
    Response response = new Response("Done", categoryList);

    return response;
}
```

and the Object response:

```
public class Response {
   private String status;
   private Object data;
   ....
}
```

I have tried many different ways, with @GetMapping and so on.. but I always received 404 bad request.

Thanks a lot

---

Yes yes my question was how convert the pojo automatically with jackson library but after Spring 3 I needs a lot of bean configuration and than I modify my controller as follows:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/categoryFilter")
public String showCategory() {
    List<Categoria> catList = categoryService.getAllCategories();

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(catList);
    return json.toString();
}
```

Your code:

```
var resObjs= JSON.stringify(result);
var cats= JSON.parse(resObjs);
$("#category-form").append('<form:form method="post" action="searchShop.html" modelAttribute="Categoria">');
$.each(JSON.parse(cats), function(i, obj) {
        $("#category-form").append('<form:input path="nome" value="'+obj.nome+'" />' + obj.nome); // this line
        });
$("#category-form").append('<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>');
$("#category-form").append('</form:form>');
```

Please take a look to the line inside the $.each, that line visualiza an input type with value the string +obj.name+ follows by the effective value of variable (the name of category).. why I can't put dinamically value right there?? I'm going mad..
Thank you

Comment: The URL part `categoryFilter.html` looks like it returns HTML, not JSON. What *does* it return? How did you implement the Spring code that responds to this URL?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can append the json values to a div,  this is what i did for populating selection dropdown with json data, something similar can be done for forms as well.

```
success: function (responseJson) {
        var responseObjects= JSON.stringify(responseJson);

        var categories= JSON.parse(responseObjects);
        $('#divid').empty();
        $('#divid').append($('<option value="0">').text("Select Variant"));

        $.each(categories, function(i, obj) { $("#divid").append(('<option> 
         </option>').val(obj.id).html(obj.value));});
    }
```